rf question from razavi

I have a question about this example, I don't understand why the AM part is canceled while the other one isn't.  Can somebody explain it in detail?

An AM signal varies in amplitude while an FM signal varies in frequency. By putting a signal through a hard limiter the amplitude variations are removed, but the frequency variations remain. Think if a sine wave that varies in amplitude from 100 mV to 300 mV, and varies in frequency from 1 kHz to 2 kHz. If you put it through a circuit that limits the amplitude to 100 mV you will eliminate the AM component, but the frequency variations will remain. This is done in FM receivers, the RF signal gets mixed down to an IF signal which then goes through a limiter circuit to make the amplitude constant

Can we get a source for the images? Can you be more specific?

this an example from razavi rf microelectronics book

Can you provide a citation? Edit the question please.

i'm new here,what do you mean by citation?

Something like this: https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/mla_style/mla_formatting_and_style_guide/mla_works_cited_page_books.html#:~:text=Basic%20Book%20Format&text=Last%20Name%2C%20First%20Name.,is%20unknown%20in%20North%20America.

If you copy someones image out of a book you should cite it or it's plagiarism

An AM signal varies in amplitude while an FM signal varies in frequency. By putting a signal through a hard limiter the amplitude variations are removed, but the frequency variations remain.
Think if a sine wave that varies in amplitude from 100 mV to 300 mV, and varies in frequency from 1 kHz to 2 kHz. If you put it through a circuit that limits the amplitude to 100 mV you will eliminate the AM component, but the frequency variations will remain.
This is done in FM receivers, the RF signal gets mixed down to an IF signal which then goes through a limiter circuit to make the amplitude constant, the output of the detector will then only rely on the frequency of the signal. This eliminates a lot of interference which is generally noise that varies in amplitude.

correct...thanks,one more thing,why do you say this circuit is a limiter?

@pmpo I didn't say it's a limiter, the text from the book says 'Assume that the differential pair experiences "hard limiting"'.
